# C++ unique_ptr separate declaration and instantiation

Tags: c++, instantiation, unique-ptr

Maybe this is a very simple question. But as a Java programmer I'm still struggeling how to instantiate objects correctly in C++. I got a member variable in my class and I can't instantiate it in the instantiation list of the class constructor (because it depends on some cofiguration values):

```
class SomeClass{    
  private:
  ObjectType mObject; //declaration and instantiation??

  public: 
  SomeClass()/*:mObject(valueA,valueB)*/{ 
     //read config here...
     //now we got valueA and valueB
     mObject = mObject(valueA,valueB);
  }    
};
```

The code as shown above does not work, because the C++ tries to call `mObject()` before `mObject(valueA, valueB)` is even reached.
I got two question:

1. Do I need to use a pointer in this case?
2. How can I use a `unique_ptr` for this? I already searched for examples but didn't find one with separate declaration and instantiation. (like [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh279676.aspx))

I get an error if I try to use `unique_ptr` like this:

```
 #include <memory>
  class SomeClass{    
      private:
      std::unique_ptr<ObjectType> mObject;

      public: 
      SomeClass(){ 
         //read config here...
         //now we got valueA and valueB
         mObject = new ObjectType(valueA,valueB);
      }    
    };
```

the Error is:

> Error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are
>   'std::unique_ptr' and 'ObjectType*')
>        mObject= new ObjectType(valueA, valueB)

Maybe there is even a better solution which I didn't see yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the value of a unique_pointer like this:

```
mObject.reset(new ObjectType(valueA,valueB));
```

Check out the docs here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/reset/

Answer (score 3):

You really should try to properly initialize `mObject` in the constructor initializer list, even if it's difficult to do so. You say you need to read some config to get `valueA` and `valueB`. You can call a private static function to read the config and then pass the values read to another constructor.

```
private:
static std::pair<A, B> readConfig();
SomeClass(std::pair<A, B> p) : mObject(p.first, p.second) {}
public:
SomeClass() : SomeClass(readConfig()) {}
```

There are a number of advantages of doing so, for example:

- You will know for sure that the `ObjectType` object will really live as long as the `SomeClass` object lives; there is no chance of accidentally destroying it earlier.
- If the `SomeClass` object is `const`, you avoid accidentally modifying the `ObjectType` object. A `std::unique_ptr` member would have "shallow `const`" semantics.

If you really want to make `mObject` a `std::unique_ptr` then here are two ways:

```
mObject.reset(new ObjectType(valueA, valueB));
```

and

```
mObject = std::make_unique<ObjectType>(valueA, valueB);
```

Comment: How could I accidentally destroy mObject "earlier"? I thought `unique_ptr` will manage the lifetime of the underlying raw pointer and assumed, that if I declare the `unique_ptr` as a member of `SomeClass` the lifetime would be as long as the lifetime of the surrounding `SomeClass` object. Am I wrong?

Comment: @little_planet:  `mObject.reset()` will destroy the pointed-to object early

Comment: Other advantage: the class is still copyable and not moveable only.